# How do I subscribe to a question?

Tags: support, bookmarks

I would like to be able to subscribe to question changes to receive notifications and eventually emails.

Comment: You can favourite a question by clicking on the star to your left, or subscript to a question's feed by going to the "question feed" link to the bottom right of the page.

Comment: Are you sure this is how favorite currently works? i found and i quote "Changes to the question will eventually (but do not currently) notify users who have favorited the question." at http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/53580/154185

Comment: Not a notification as in the red signal at the top. But there will be a sign on your favourites tab.

Comment: I want notifications or eventually will forget to manually visit the favorites tab. I guess i can live with the question feed for now but i think this was correctly labeled as feature-request before your edits.

Comment: If you were aware of the existing features and really wanted to request additional email notifications, by all means revert my edits. But then you might want to give it a more clear title and state how the current features to not fit your needs.

Comment: You're right, i think your first comment + your clarifications about the sign at the favorites tab is the correct answer. Feel free to turn it into an answer so i can accept it. Thanks!

Comment: This isn't a duplicate. An answer might be "favourite it", but it may not be a good answer even.