# Can we subscribe to have notifications for favorited questions or possibly a subscribe button?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, notifications, bookmarks

Is there any way to get the same updates of [the my favorite questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252512/whats-the-use-of-favourite-this-question) but instantly in my messages inbox (in the same way we get inbox notifications when someone mentioned `@` me in a comment). Or to be able to subscribe to updates on a question?

So we can receive an inbox message when any activity happens on the question we favorite: comments, edits, answers.

It would be much the same as the notifications that the author of a question would receive.

[image]

Comment: Nice idea! Something like the "subscribe" button on github would be really useful! For example you come across an unanswered question to which you would also like to know the answer, you could subscribe to it and get a notification if it gets answered. The current behaviour of favourites is not useful for this because a) you have to remember to check it regularly b) a lot of false positives when posts gets bumped by community etc.

Comment: @rene If your inbox is full, you can opt-out or don't subscribe to any question.

Comment: maybe something like this: https://stackapps.com/questions/6460/stack-exchange-desktop-notifications

Comment: @rene like this in the events it detects, but instead of detecting these events for the questions only opened in other tabs, I want to get notifications for any question I want without being opened in other tab. You know what rene.... this userscript inspired me, I will try to make a userscript that does exactly what I want.

Comment: Oi @Accountantم let me know if that edit describes what you want. To me it was clear, but I have been known to misunderstand things on occassion :)

Comment: Interesting idea. Not sure if it's worth the development time, there's some other things the site needs, but still an interesting request. I gave it an upvote, as it's actually a good idea.

Comment: @YvetteColomb thank you very much for taking the time to edit it, yes the edits describe what I want very much, this line summarized it all **"It would be much the same as the notifications that the author of a question would receive."**

Comment: @Accountantم excellent. I [mentioned you](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/47307349#47307349) in this chat room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197438/the-meta-room

Comment: Also related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310052/follow-a-question-by-notifications https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323874/subscribe-to-or-follow-comments https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253855/how-do-i-subscribe-to-a-question?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: And on Meta.SE https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45360/subscribing-to-questions-and-comments-that-dont-belong-to-you https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34481/subscribe-to-others-questions https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86877/how-to-follow-a-question-on-stackoverflow https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13988/how-can-i-watch-a-question-in-stack-overflow https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13066/watching-questions-for-answers https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/mark-questions-to-receive-notifications-and-updates etc

Comment: In summary: people want this feature, it does not get implemented.

Comment: @Accountantم In case you succeed with the userscript project, please ping me! I would really love to use it!

Comment: @Marijn thanks for the links

Comment: @samcarter *" In case you succeed with the userscript project, please ping me! I would really love to use it!"* .... OK sure :)